# How can I convert a string of characters to multiple int values? C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm working on homework and the professor wants us to make this function. I'm having trouble understanding how to create it. This is the code I have modified several times. I have tried storing the string in array, or char array. And I tried using pointers. Below is a picture of the homework and my code I currently have.

[image: Homework Function]

```
    int valueOf(char a) {
        string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        string* ptr = &alphabet;

        alphabet[1] = 10; 

        if (a >= 0 && a <= 9) {
            return a;
        }else if(a == alphabet.){
        

        }
    }
```

Comment: try `return a - 'a' + 10;` in your else statement

Comment: Using a pointer to a single `std::string` seems kind of pointless.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ and many other languages, characters and integers actually aren't that different. Every number or character you could possibly think of is represented in a table called ASCII. Every symbol has a numerical value associated with it. Here's an ASCII table below:

[image]

There are thousands of entries in the ASCII table, but these are the ones we care about for the time being. When you declare a character in C++, it's actually stored internally as an integer! In other words, a character variable holds the ASCII value for that character as an integer. For example, the character 'a' is stored as 97 internally. Since this is so, you can do some cool stuff with character to integer conversions.

```
int a = 'a';
```

This is valid C++ code and will store the number 97 in a.

```
char a = 97;
```

Furthermore, this is also valid and has the same effect.

Knowing these values, you can also perform arithmetic on characters.

```
char a = 97;
a -= 32;
std::cout << a << std::endl;
```

What do you think this will print?

Now let's take a look at the first part of this question. We need to be able to turn the character 9 into the integer 9. Integer 9 is obviously represented as 9 and according to the ASCII table character 9 is stored as 57. This this means that the character and integer values for 9 are 57 - 9 = 48 apart. This will work the same for all characters 0-9, since both the characters and integers 0-9 are aligned sequentially. So, to convert any character 0-9 to its integer counterpart, just subtract 48.

```
char nine = '9';
int numNime = nine - 48;
```

Hopefully this will give you a good headstart on figuring out the rest of this!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
int valueOf(char a) {
        if (isalnum(a) {
            return a-'0'; // effectively the char -48 if you forget the ascii value
        }else { return -99; } 
            //or whatever error check you have for non alphanumeric chars
    }
```

Some more char test functions can be found at:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/

*edit typo